# Access class of another module to my module typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am new to `TypeScript`. I am trying to use a class from another module in my module. how can I do it. I tried some suggestion by googling but nothing worked. any suggestion would be helpful

I have a simple module as below in file `list.ts`

```
export moduleTest {
export class List<T> {
    }
}
```

I am trying to access this from another file in same folder `initializer.ts`

```
module MyModule {
export class MyService {
    public currentCollection : List<string>;//getting error in this line
    }
}
```

this throws me error that cannot find name `List`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you did not import that class in your  `initializer.ts`

if yes, then add this code in your top of the `initializer.ts`

```
import { List } from './list.ts;
```

Comment: yes bro, i tried initially with wrong module name. now it worked